# return from multi column laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

i have laravel project

### has three column

voucherheads
vouchers
items

### and three model

Voucherhead
Voucher
Item

--
this is the tables structures 
voucherheads table

```
      Schema::create('voucherheads', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('voucher_type');
      $table->integer('voucher_dealer');
      $table->text('voucher_note')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();
```

voucher table

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('voucher_id');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_id');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_quantity');
        $table->integer('voucher_dealer');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_main_category');
        $table->integer('voucher_item_sub_category');
        $table->integer('voucher_type');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
```

and item table

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('item_id',100)->unique();
        $table->string('item_name',250);
        $table->double('item_price');
        $table->integer('item_total');
        $table->integer('item_color');
        $table->integer('item_main_category');
        $table->integer('item_sub_category');
        $table->integer('item_q_in_c');
        $table->integer('item_last_in');
        $table->integer('item_total_in');
        $table->integer('item_inserter');
        $table->integer('item_state');
        $table->integer('item_admin');
        $table->integer('item_area');
        $table->integer('item_row');
        $table->integer('item_location');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
```

now i have view folder called vouchers 
index create show edit
this is the view controller code

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data = Voucherhead::withTrashed()->find($id);
    return view('vouchers.show',compact('data'));
}
```

and inside the Voucherhead model i have this function

```
public function getVoucherData()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Voucher','voucher_id','id');
}
```

now in show.vouchers i run this code

```
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>رقم السند</td>
                <td colspan='2'>نوع السند</td>
                <td colspan='2'>لحساب</td>
                <td colspan='2'>التاريخ</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>{{$data->id}}</td>
                <td colspan='2'>{{$data->getVoucherType->vouchertype_name}}</td>
                <td colspan='2'>{{$data->getVoucherDealer->dealer_name}}</td>
                <td colspan='2'>{{$data->created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>رمز السلعة</td>
                <td>وصف السلعة</td>
                <td>العنوان</td>
                <td>عدد الكراتين</td>
                <td>تعبئة الكرتونة</td>
                <td>الفرط</td>
                <td>المجموع</td>
                <td>السعر</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($data->getVoucherData as $item)
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

now i can access the voucherhead and the voucher with one to many
how can i access the data in the item from voucher_item_id in Voucher model 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Voucher has `voucher_item_id` that means it can only have 1 `Item`. Therefore you have to add in `Voucher` class

```
public function getItem() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Voucher', 'voucher_item_id', 'item_id');
}
```

So you can access it like this

```
$voucher = Voucher::find(1);
$item = $voucher->item;
```